# Express server trouble: Cannot run "Hello World" app

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to run a "Hello world" Express server, following the instructions at https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html. When I run `node app.js`, I get the console output "Example app listening at http://localhost:3000/", as expected. However, I can't actually connect to http://localhost:3000/ in my browser. Using FireFox, I get the message "Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:3000".

I know that the server is actually alive, though, because when I run `curl http://localhost:3000` on the command line, the output is "Hello World!" I just can't connect to it in my browser for some reason (but apparently I can connect to it via the command line).

Things I've tried:

- restarting my computer
- ensuring that the "hosts" file contains the lines `127.0.0.1 localhost` and `::1 localhost`, as suggested in https://superuser.com/a/1009111
- checking if anything else is using port 3000 -- nothing else is

None of the above solutions work. What should I do?

Comment: Does it work with all your add-ons disabled?

Comment: @Evert No, it doesn't work.

Comment: does the extra `slash` at the end affect the response? Also try browser other than firefox

Comment: The extra slash doesn't matter, and it doesn't work on other browsers either (I tried Chrome and Edge).

I was actually able to run an Express server a few weeks ago, but now I can't run it anymore. What could the issue be? I know I had a Windows update installed recently, but that shouldn't have broken things.

Comment: Are you running this in WSL or straight up windows?

Comment: I use the WSL shell to run the program. I've tried running the app in Windows and in the WSL system, but neither way works.

Comment: Update: I installed node on Windows, and now I can run the app, but only if I use the Git Bash shell. Strange. At least I can run my app now, which is a relief.